# JavaScript calling controller for session clear not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am calling a `controller` that redirects url.  `Usercontroller.cs` has a `ClearSessionAnCoodkies` method.
I have added the route for this `httpget` method `ClearSessionAndCookies()`.

Used JQuery for calling the controller method to clear the session variable and  redirect tot he home page.

For some reason the call is failing and not redirecting to the home page.

Application says 404 page not found.     Not sure why the call is failing :(

```
    The following is the controller, router, and asp.net call
    ----------

    **UserController.cs**

        [HttpGet]
            public IHttpActionResult ClearSessionAndCookies()
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
                HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll();
                var host = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority); 

                return Redirect(host + "/cp");     
            }

    **Routing**

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                   name: "User",
                   routeTemplate: "api/User",
                   defaults: new { action = "ClearSessionAndCookies", controller = "User" }
               );

    **JavaScirpt**

    function RedirectToWelcomePage() {
        message = "Session expired. You will be redirected to home page.";
        $('#sessionTimeoutTitle').text(message);
        $('#sessionTimeoutModal').modal('show');

        var url = 'api/User/ClearSessionAndCookies';

            $.post(url, function (res) {
                if (res.Success) {
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                    window.location.href = res.RedirectUrl;
                }
            });     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring the action as Get and then are calling this with a post.

[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ClearSessionAndCookies()

$.post(url, function (res) {

Remove the  [HttpGet] attribute and this will work.

Comment: Thanks, Mauri.  It should be "get", instead of post.

Comment: Yes, the Ajax call and the declaration need to be compatible

Answer (score 0):

Your route map says that if a user hits `api/User` it will call `ClearSessionAndCookies`. If you want the action in the url you may need to update your routing.

I highly recommend Route Attributes as they are cleaner to ready. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing